# Facebook ads API how to get the credit left by account?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I could'nt find in the Facebook Ads API a way to get the credit left of a facebook Ads account.

It seems it's the only information not available in the ads api ?
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adaccount/

Any ideas where to find this information?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"balance" property should be one you are looking for. It's not documented but it's in response for adaccount object (act_XXX).

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. But I can't find the "credit left" on one account. The 'balance' property is actually the credit spent. I found as well the amount spent which is different. But I can not find the credit left on the ad account. Any other ideas?

Comment: It seems not available in API. You can simulate it using amount_spent which is not same though. More at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adaccount/.

Answer (score 0):

Balance is just the amount of money unpaid to the account. if you are managing dozens of accounts with credit spread out, there is no way to see what the balance for the entire account